# How to best merge containers/packages

Tags: algorithm, packing

So this is the situation.

I have a certain number of containers.
Those containers can have a max number of items.
What i would like to do is to merge those containers so that in the end i have hopefully less containers that are mostly filled.

Example:
Let's say i have 5 containers with a max of 5 items

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

and they are all randomly filled [#items]

```
[3][1][4][5][2]
```

What i did to try and solve this was the following:
Method 1
-Take the smallest and merge it with the biggest where possible (1+4 would work but 1+5 would not)

Method 2
-Take the two biggest that can be merged

Right now, to evaluate a container list i use

```
sum((ContainerMaxSize-ActualSize)^2)
```

for all containers in a list.

Any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: `hopefully less containers that are mostly filled` is a wishy washy requirement. You need to be specific about the requirement, what you tried and what is did wrong. Currently your question is too broad.

Comment: The original containers are a red herring; this is the well studied [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Comment: There is no (known) perfect algorithm, [see this image](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/images/Chapter-Use_cases_and_examples/binPackingIsNpComplete1.png).